# VBA get unique value from range and result input every second row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros that I would like to combine but somehow its not going well...
I want a macro that will get only unique values from a range and input them into another sheet every second row starting from row no 3

Could anyone tell me how should I combine those two macros?
I have tried to change `.Font.Size = 20` with `Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)` but it didn't work.

```
Sub UniqueValue()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
X = Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next
Range("F1:F" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End Sub





Sub EverySecond()
Dim EndRow As Long
EndRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For ColNum = 5 To EndRow Step 2
        Range(Cells(ColNum, 2), Cells(ColNum, 2)).Font.Size = 20
    Next ColNum
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the names of the worksheets and the first cell addresses? What has the font size got to do with all of it?

Comment: Please, edit your question and explain **in words** what you try accomplishing. Your two codes do not match the title and your 'explanation"... What does "input them into another sheet every second row" should mean? Do you suggest that one of the code does that? Then, please answer the clarification question from the above comment. Is it somewhere in your question a mention regarding any font change? Do you want extracting the unique values and only place them in another column, followed by changing the font in the previously processed range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Unique Values to Every Other Row

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UniqueEveryOther()

    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
1
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the unqiue values from the array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To srCount
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the unqiue values from the dictionary to the array.
    
    ReDim Data(1 To 2 * dict.Count - 1, 1 To 1)
    r = -1
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        r = r + 2
        Data(r, 1) = Key
    Next Key
    
    ' Write the unique values from the array to the destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        .Resize(r).Value = Data
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - r + 1).Offset(r).Clear
        '.EntireColumn = AutoFit
    End With
    
    'wb.Save
    
    MsgBox "Uniques populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```